# WebLogic Bridge Message: "Failure of Web Server bridge: No backend server available for connection..."

Tags: configuration, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have an application (packaged software from a vendor) that runs on Oracle WebLogic.

There are few operations that, if I try them, I consistently get the following error page:

> **(WebLogic Bridge Message) Failure of Web Server bridge: No backend server available for connection: timed out after 10 seconds or idempotent set to OFF or method not idempotent.**

The error occurs consistently almost exactly five minutes after I try the operation.

The page does not look like the typical error page you get when the application logic fails.  It looks like something to do with the infrastructure (e.g., WebLogic configuration).

I am pursuing the issue with the software vendor, but that's not going well.

Has anyone seen this message and/or suggest an approach for diagnosing the root cause here?

Comment: Looks like you are using a Proxy Server between Browser and Weblogic Server. By seeing the error it's evident that proxy server unable to connect to back-end WLS server. You may have to enable proxy debugs to get more info. Check https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/webtier/PLGWL/plugin_params.htm#PLGWL475

Comment: @NaveenHiremath Thank you for that link.  I will review it and perhaps there may be something our infrastructure team can do.

Comment: I also faced this issue recently. The reason behind this issue is, your application might be trying to connect to other servers outside of WebLogic server. In my case, WebLogic server was trying to connect to SMTP server and since SMTP server was down, it gave us the same error page every after 5 minutes that you mentioned. The default waiting time was set to 5 minutes. So, you first need to make sure what are the other servers your WebLogic server is trying to connect to. Once you identify it, probably it will help you to solve the issue. Hope this information helps.

Comment: @AnishPanthi Thank you, that is useful but that was not my particular issue.  I've since learned that this error message is kind of a "catch all".  It happens for any number of different reasons and, by itself, the message means little more than "something's wrong".