# Not able to track the issue from Weblogic to Oracle

Tags: oracle, networking, weblogic, fiddler

I am getting the below error in one of the QA Environment where the calls from WebLogic to Oracle takes long time and get the below error. Same code base on different QA Levels it works fine. I couldn't figure it out only i am getting this issue on only one environment. How do i debug the issue?

**Failure of Web Server bridge:**
No backend server available for connection: timed out after 10 seconds or idempotent set to OFF or method not idempotent.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/59758283/5174436.  I have been pursuing an SR on Oracle for this issue for almost 3 months now.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Can you try directly accessing it from Weblogic Host and Port and see how much time it takes? Either backend server is not responding or call is taking more than 10 seconds to connect hence timing out. You need to enable debugs to see what's wrong.

Comment: @NaveenHiremath I have tried from weblogic and i got the response back after 6 minutes.  But the same code and same data on L1 environment it comes in 30 seconds.

Comment: Then you have to check why in your environment it's taking more time and set timeout accordingly.